# How to convert a random distributed vector to datetime object in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, datetime

I have a vector with random distributed values from 0 to 10 in increasing value, e.g. [1 3 4 9 10]. How can i convert this vector to a datetime object with time values between e.g. November and December such that these numbers represent the corresponding times in between?

Example, if x = [1 2 3] and I want the time period the whole January, then the output should be [1st January, 15th January, 30th January], according to their relative values.

Example, if x = [0 0.5 9 10] and we have entire January then 0 should map to the first day in January and 10 to the last day in January. 0.5 will map to the date at part 0.5/10 = 1/20 starting from the first January to the last. That date will be approximately 30 * 1 / 20 = 1 day and a half into January. Now, the 9 will in the same way be in position 9 / 10 of 30 days. That is 30 * 9 / 10 = 27. That is the 27th day of January. So the output should be [1st January, 1.5th January, 27th January, 30th January] in datetime format.

Comment: how does `x = [1,2,3]` correspond to `[1st January, 15th January, 30th January]` as per your logic?

Comment: Okay. So assume we have the vector x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12] and the time interval january to december. Then the bijection will be 1 -> January, 2 -> February ... 11 -> November, 12 -> December. Another example, assume x = [1 2 3 4 ... 30] and the time is January. Then each number in the vector x maps to the corresponding day in January. That is 1 -> 1st January, 2 -> 2nd January ... 30 -> 30th January. Now, assume x = [1 2 3] and we again have January. Then the first value is 1st January and the last is 30th January. Since we only have one value between it will be the day in the middle

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datenum` and some basic arithmetic to arrive at the following solution:

```
formatIn = 'dd.mm.yyyy';
d1 = '01.01.2017'; % user input, should be the earlier date
d2 = '31.01.2017'; % user input, should be the later date
x = [0 0.5 5 7 10]; % user input

d1 = datenum(d1,formatIn);
d2 = datenum(d2,formatIn);

daysAfter_d1 = d2-d1;
x = x/max(x);
addDays = round(daysAfter_d1*x);
interpolatedDates = d1 + addDays;
datestr(interpolatedDates,formatIn)

ans =

01.01.2017
03.01.2017
16.01.2017
22.01.2017
31.01.2017
```